# How can I recover data from a VirtualBox VM with a missing snapshot?

Tags: virtualbox, data-recovery

I have a VirtualBox VM with several snapshots, though none recent.  I tried to merge the current state with the most recent snapshot via the GUI.  The merge failed.  Now, when I try to start my VM, it says

```
 Could not open the medium '/home/username/VirtualBox VMs/Winders/Snapshots/{787ce0d8-e81d-4dbe-8b64-f3719cea56ee}.vdi'
```

When I try `ls -l ~/VirtualBox VMs/Winders/Snapshots`, I get

```
Mar  2  2017 {1beacf46-0f0f-406d-9a31-e6c18aa55260}.vdi
Sep 26  2016 2016-09-26T15-07-17-368576000Z.sav
Mar  2  2017 2017-03-02T12-55-36-577344000Z.sav
May 30  2017 2017-05-30T14-09-39-956374000Z.sav
Nov  5  2016 {96d2faab-9441-4c76-882e-72e03603329c}.vdi
Dec 14  2016 {9f2b3a52-1539-478c-9c25-db323c6cc6b3}.vdi
Oct 19 16:40 {b0f5d1a4-1456-4866-82e4-cf039005249b}.vdi
May 30  2017 {b9b4d568-51a9-4eae-9a49-d093a4ae2b6d}.vdi
```

Recovering the missing file seems like it's not an option.  I've restarted the computer since this happened, not knowing I had a missing file.

I mostly only care about one file on the VM.  Is it possible to extract that file from my VDI files even though I'm missing a snapshot?

I tried `vboxmanage clonehd {b0f5d1a4-1456-4866-82e4-cf039005249b}.vdi oct19.raw` on a copy after changing its UUID with `VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid {b0f5d1a4-1456-4866-82e4-cf039005249b}.vdi`, but it also says `Could not open the medium '/home/username/VirtualBox VMs/Winders/Snapshots/{787ce0d8-e81d-4dbe-8b64-f3719cea56ee}.vdi'`